Pyomo, file path issue
I have the current code provided to me by my thesis supervisor. he advised me that the code should run without any changes. i have the file and code saved in the same folders and have edited the excel file according but i still receive running errors. can anyone notice any immediate issues at face value ( this is my first time ever using python so i am not entirely sure what to be looking out for).
This is the error i get : 1 Set Declarations
t_meas : Size=0, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
Not constructed
4 Param Declarations
s_ini : Size=0, Index=None, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
Not constructed
s_meas : Size=0, Index=t_meas, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
Not constructed
x_ini : Size=0, Index=None, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
Not constructed
x_meas : Size=0, Index=t_meas, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
Not constructed
5 Var Declarations
Y : Size=0, Index=None
Not constructed
k_s : Size=0, Index=None
Not constructed
s : Size=0, Index=t
Not constructed
u_max : Size=0, Index=None
Not constructed
x : Size=0, Index=t
Not constructed
1 Objective Declarations
obj : Size=0, Index=None, Active=True
Not constructed
3 Constraint Declarations
dsdtcon : Size=0, Index=t, Active=True
Not constructed
dxdtcon : Size=0, Index=t, Active=True
Not constructed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\kaden\OneDrive\Desktop\Thesis\Python\Pyomo\Test-Code.py", line 61, in 
m.pprint()
File "C:\Users\kaden\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\component.py", line 573, in pprint
self._pprint_base_impl(
File "C:\Users\kaden\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\component.py", line 473, in _pprint_base_impl
_fcn(ostream, _key, _data_dict[_key])
File "C:\Users\kaden\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\block.py", line 2185, in _pprint_callback
data._pprint_blockdata_components(ostream)
File "C:\Users\kaden\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\block.py", line 1806, in _pprint_blockdata_components
self.component(key).pprint(ostream=indented_ostream)
File "C:\Users\kaden\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\component.py", line 580, in pprint
*self._pprint()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kaden\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\constraint.py", line 750, in _pprint
self.items(),
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kaden\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\indexed_component.py", line 590, in items
return ((s, self[s]) for s in self.keys(sort))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kaden\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\indexed_component.py", line 474, in keys
ans = iter(self._index_set)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "", line 2, in iter
RuntimeError: Cannot iterate over AbstractOrderedScalarSet 'AbstractOrderedScalarSet' before it has been constructed (initialized): 'iter' is an attribute on an Abstract component and cannot be accessed until the component has been fully constructed (converted to a Concrete component) using AbstractModel.create_instance() or AbstractOrderedScalarSet.construct().
ive trired renaming and resetting out the excel file and copying the error into LLMs and seeing if that helps but all have been to no avail

This is unreadable.
